# openapi-generator-maven-plugin breaks old feign with @QueryMap

Tags: maven, swagger, swagger-codegen, feign, openapi-generator

Code generation for feign works fine with `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:2.2.2`, unfortunatelly I was forced to move to `openapi-generator-maven-plugin:2.2.14` or `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:2.2.14`. When this generators processed schemas with methods having optional parameters, they duplicate method with one map parameter with annotation `@QueryMap(encoded=true)`.

Example:

```
/**
   * Note, this is equivalent to the other <code>someMethod</code> method,
   * but with the query parameters collected into a single Map parameter. This
   * is convenient for services with optional query parameters, especially when
   * used with the {@link ApiV1CodesGetQueryParams} class that allows for
   * building up this map in a fluent style.
   * @param queryParams Map of query parameters as name-value pairs
   *   <p>The following elements may be specified in the query map:</p>
   *   <ul>
   *   <li>p1 - param1 (optional)</li>
   *   <li>p2 - param2 (optional)</li>
   *   </ul>

   */
  @RequestLine("GET /api/v1/someMethod?p1={p1}&p2={p2}")
  @Headers({
  "Accept: application/json",
  })
  Response  someMethod(@QueryMap(encoded=true) Map<String, Object> queryParams);
```

Old version of feign lib has no `@QueryMap(encoded=true)` and so compilation of java code failed. I have no opportunity to upgrade feign lib, so I won't to disable this code generator's feature but can't find any switch for it. Can anybody switch this annoying feature off?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling it with a switch, you can customize the Java Feign generator's template to remove `QueryMap` and then generate code using the customized templates with the `-t` CLI option.

Comment: I found source template here:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/libraries/feign/api.mustache

Looks ugly but can be cloned and fixed